# The currect density in materials of uniform resistivity

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

Inside an infinitely large piece of material that fills the whole $\mathbb R^3$ space with uniform resistivity $\lambda$ (which letter should I use, when $\rho$ has been used for charge density?), there are two points with position vectors $-\mathbf d$ and $\mathbf d$. The positive and negative terminals of a voltage source (battery) of emf $2\mathcal E$ are connected to $-\mathbf d$ and $\mathbf d$ respectively.

You many assume that the electric potential inside two small spheres with radius $a$ centred around  $-\mathbf d$ and $\mathbf d$ to be fixed.

Now a current is produced inside the material. Let's denote the current density by $\mathbf J(\mathbf r)=\rho\mathbf v(\mathbf r)$, where $\mathbf v$ is the drift velocity.

Question: Can I find an expression for $\mathbf J$ and $\rho$ in terms of other quantities (and some integrals perhaps)? I have tried to use the maxwell equations, but apparently, they are not useful.

This is NOT a homework question. I have come up with it myself.

Comment: Is the material geometry arbitrary?

Comment: @Puk I have edited the question. It should fill the whole space - so we are thinking about an infinitely large piece.

Comment: I think there is a problem with the boundary conditions: fixed potential difference across two points embedded in this material. The problem is that assuming the material is linear, because of the "current crowding" that occurs around these points, the potential must abruptly change to the average value near these points, i.e. the potential drops only occur "on" these points. A physical solution is possible if you allow the constant potential boundaries to be e.g. spherical with some radius $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Puk So could you write an answer if I allow them to be spheres?

Comment: You're not going to be able to come up with a consistent answer. The reason boils down to the question: how is the battery connected to the points to complete the circuit? See, if you don't have some sort of wire or something moving through space you're violating charge conservation, and electromagnetic theory is not consistent without it. My own suggestions are: specify that the resistive material is infinite and flat, specify this problem is in 4 or more spatial dimensions, or explain how you build a coherent theory without charge conservation.

Comment: I'd need to think it through more cafefully, but can't the standard solution to the [infinite resistor grid](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath668/kmath668.htm) be adapted here? I.e. drive symmetric currents from infinity into and out of each sphere and superpose the results to get your field? So you'd get something resembling a dipole $\vec{J}$ field between the contacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Faraday's law, at steady state,
$$ \vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E} = -\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} = 0 $$
so since $\vec{E}$ is curl-free, it is the (negative) gradient of the electrostatic potential $V$:
$$ \vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla}V. $$

From the continuity equation and Ohm's law, at steady state and for uniform electrical conductivity $\sigma = 1/\lambda$,
$$ \vec{\nabla} · (\sigma \vec{E}) + \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} =0 $$
$$ \vec{\nabla}\sigma · \vec{E} +  \sigma\vec{\nabla}·\vec{E} + \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} = 0 $$
$$ \vec{\nabla} ·\vec{E} = 0 $$
$$ \vec{\nabla}^2 V = 0. $$
This is the differential equation you must solve (Laplace's equation), with constant potential boundary conditions on the spherical boundries.

I'm not sure if an analytical solution exists (I wouldn't be surprised if it does), but we can obtain approximate solution for $V$ for small $a$. If there were two point charges $Q$ and $-Q$ at $\vec{d}$ and $-\vec{d}$ in vacuum, the potential at points not on these charges also satisfies Laplace's equation. In this simplified problem, according to Coulomb's law, the potential in the vicinity of the point charge at $\pm\vec{d}$ would be
$$ V(\vec{r}) \approx \pm \frac{A}{\lVert\vec{r}\mp\vec{d}\rVert} $$
where $A$ is some proportionality constant that is yet to be determined. If $ a \ll d $, a distance $a$ away from $\pm\vec{r}$, we enforce

$$  V = \pm \mathcal{E} \approx \pm \frac{A}{a} $$
$$ A = a\mathcal{E} $$

The potential everywhere is given approximately (to the extent $a \ll d$ is valid) by
$$ V(\vec{r}) = a\mathcal{E}\left(-\frac{1}{\lVert\vec{r} + \vec{d}\rVert}+\frac{1}{\lVert\vec{r} - \vec{d}\rVert}\right). $$
You can see here why $a = 0$ is problematic. Then,
$$ \vec{E} = -\vec{\nabla}V = a\mathcal{E}\left(-\frac{\vec{r} + \vec{d}}{\lVert\vec{r} + \vec{d}\rVert^3}+\frac{\vec{r} - \vec{d}}{\lVert\vec{r} - \vec{d}\rVert^3}\right) $$
and 
$$\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E} = \sigma a\mathcal{E}\left(-\frac{\vec{r} + \vec{d}}{\lVert\vec{r} + \vec{d}\rVert^3}+\frac{\vec{r} - \vec{d}}{\lVert\vec{r} - \vec{d}\rVert^3}\right). $$
The charge density can be determined from Gauss' law:
$$ \rho = \vec{\nabla}·(\epsilon \vec{E}) = \vec{\nabla}\epsilon · \vec{E} + \epsilon \vec{\nabla}·\vec{E} = \vec{\nabla}\epsilon · \vec{E}. $$
Given $\epsilon$ as a function of position, you can use this to find $\rho$. If $\epsilon$ is uniform, then we simply have $\rho = 0$. This is typically a good approximation within a conductor at steady state.

Comment: What is $A$? It doesn't seem to be a standard quantity

Comment: So if $\epsilon$ is uniform, drift velocity must be infinite?

Comment: Also, is this true also for lamina and any other shapes of the material?

Comment: According to Coulomb's law, the potential due to a point charge in a uniform dielectric is proportional to $1/r$, and $A$ is just the proportionality constant, here determined from the boundary conditions. Drift velocity doesn't have to be infinite. $\vec{J}=\rho\vec{v}$ gives the current density due to mobile charge carriers. It does not necessarily apply to the total charge density since the charge distribution is made up of stationary and free charge carriers, and there can be different types of carriers moving with different average drift velocities (electrons and holes, etc.).

Comment: If the assumption of a constant electrical conductivity is realistic, for materials that don't extend to infinity, you would still need to solve Laplace's equation, but with additional boundary conditions. If the material terminates at a boundary bordering a non-conductive material, the boundary condition here would be $\hat{n}·\vec{J} = 0$, i.e. the normal component of the current density is zero. The approximate expressions I gave for $V$, $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{J}$ would obviously no longer apply in general.

Comment: Thank you a lot！